# bPopup opens centre-aligned in one page and left-aligned in other

Tags: jquery, iframe, position, css-position, bpopup

I'm using the [bPopup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) plugin to open an `iframe` on two separate pages.

I've written a small script which creates the iframe and "pops it up". This same script (exact URL etc) is referenced on both of my pages:

```
jQuery('#student_iframe_container').css({
      'display': 'none'
});

jQuery('body').on("click", ".student_iframe_popup", function() {
      jQuery('#student_iframe_container').remove();

      var popUpHTML = '<div id="student_iframe_container"><div class="b-close"><img src="/user/74/187888.png" title="Close" /></div><iframe></iframe></div>';
      jQuery('body').append(popUpHTML);

      jQuery('.b-close').css({
            'background-color': 'none',
            'padding': '8px',
            'font-size': '14px',
            'font-weight': 'bold',
            'width': '52px',
            'text-align': 'center',
            'cursor': 'pointer',
            'overflow' : 'auto'
      });

      jQuery('iframe').css({
            'margin': '0px auto',
            'background-color': 'none',
            'border': 'none'
      });

    var student_id = 'student_' + jQuery(this).attr("id");

    jQuery('iframe').attr("width", 800);
    jQuery('iframe').attr("height", 670);
    jQuery('iframe').attr("id", student_id);
    jQuery('iframe').attr("src", '/index.phtml?d=825090');

    jQuery('#student_iframe_container').bPopup({
            position: ['auto', 2]
      });
});
```

The idea of this script is that I can whack `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="student_iframe_popup" id="123456">student</a>` into my pages and the script will do the rest.

On both of my pages the pop-up `iframe` works correctly. The issues lies with alignment: on one page the `iframe` correctly appears horizontally centre-aligned but on the other it appears left-aligned.

Correct alignment on **Assign Flags** page
[image: Correct alignment]

Incorrect alignment on **My Flags** page
[image: Incorrect alignment]

If I look at the HTML in FireBug it's fairly messy:

**Assign Flags**:

```
<div class="b-modal __b-popup1__" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); position: fixed; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0.7; z-index: 9998; cursor: pointer;"></div>
<div id="student_iframe_container" style="left: 48.5px; position: absolute; top: 2px; z-index: 9999; opacity: 1; display: block;">
    <div class="b-close" style="padding: 8px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; width: 52px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; overflow: auto;">
        <img title="Close" src="/user/74/187888.png">
    </div>
    <iframe width="800" height="670" style="margin: 0px auto; border: medium none;" id="student_138871" src="/index.phtml?d=825090"></iframe>
</div>
```

The `student_iframe_popup` class is used in this segment of HTML:

```
<li>
    <a id="138929" class="student_iframe_popup" href="javascript:void(0);">Student Name</a>
    <div>23<img alt="Red Flags" src="/user/74/187894.png">&nbsp;0<img alt="Interventions" src="/user/74/187895.png"></div>
</li>
```

**My Flags**:

```
<div class="b-modal __b-popup1__" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); position: fixed; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0.7; z-index: 9998; cursor: pointer;"></div>
<div id="student_iframe_container" style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 2px; z-index: 9999; opacity: 1;">
    <div class="b-close" style="padding: 8px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; width: 52px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; overflow: auto;">
        <img title="Close" src="/user/74/187888.png">
    </div>
    <iframe width="800" height="670" style="margin: 0px auto; border: medium none;" id="student_138978" src="/index.phtml?d=825090"></iframe>
</div>
```

The `student_iframe_popup` class is used in this segment of HTML:

```
<tr class="open">
    <td class="student">
        <a id="138978" class="student_iframe_popup" href="javascript:void(0);">Student Name</a>
    </td>
    <td>2nd Oct 2013</td>
    <td>10:24am</td>
    <td>IT Misuse</td>
    <td>Behaviour Unit</td>
    <td>Registration</td>
    <td>Referred to tutor</td>
    <td id="1994"><select><option value="O">Pending</option><option value="C">Completed</option></select></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="centre"><img title="Notify administrator of mistake made on Flag given to Joshua Nichol?" src="/user/74/187888.png" id="1994"></td>
</tr>
```

Associated CSS:

```
#container table { width: 100%; }
#container table img { width: 16px; }
#container th { text-align: left; border-bottom: 2px solid #999; padding-bottom: 2px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10px; }
#container tr.open { background-color: #ffd6d6; }
#container tr.no_action { background-color: #ffead6; }
#container td { padding: 8px 0 4px 0; font-size: 12px; }
#container tr.border td {  border-bottom: 1px solid #999; padding: 4px 0 8px 0; font-size: 11px; }
.student { font-weight: bold; padding-left: 5px; }
```

Obviously the discrepancy lies with these lines:

Right...

```
<div id="student_iframe_container" style="left: 48.5px; position: absolute; top: 2px; z-index: 9999; opacity: 1; display: block;">
```

Wrong...

```
<div id="student_iframe_container" style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 2px; z-index: 9999; opacity: 1;">
```

However, it isn't me that's writing those styles - it's bPopup. Neither of my pages have any CSS styles relating to bPopup; the only ones I'm changing are those in the JavaScript file at the top of this post.

Does anyone know, therefore, why bPopup decides to `left:0px` on one page and `left:48.5px` on another?

Comment: Odd behaviour! What version of bPopup are you using? Do you get this issue in different browsers (e.g. Firefox, IE, Chrome)? Also can you include the HTML where the "student_iframe_popup" class is used?

Comment: Latest version as of when I posted this question (can't check because, oddly, bPopup website is blocked at work!). Yeah, just checked, identical behaviour in all three browsers. I'll amend my OP with the "calling" HTML now.

Comment: Lol at bPopup being blocked at the workplace >_< Can you also include the CSS of the "Student" class?

Comment: @Fresh I've added that to the post now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a width to your div in your javascript:

```
var popUpHTML = '<div id="student_iframe_container" style="width:800px"><div class="b-close"><img src="/user/74/187888.png" title="Close" /></div><iframe></iframe></div>';
```

(Of course you could use a class for that div.  Using the style within the div is just a quick test.)

In bPopup the code to get the horizontal position is

```
hPos = fixedHPos ? o.position[0] : (wW - $popup.outerWidth(true)) / 2
```

Your wW (window width) is about equalling your popup width.  If you set the popup width in the div, I think it will fix it.

Comment: Well I was just about to tell you that this didn't work until I realised you missed off the `px` on your `style=` definition. Adding your line (with the `px` ;) has fixed my problem beautifully. Thanks BQB!

Comment: Glad it worked.  I think Fresh and I were on the same path.  I edited my answer to include px.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's late but I've started to look into this.

I've managed to crudely get your HTML, jQuery and CSS in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/4NB6x/). It ain't pretty!

Note that in my fiddle I have added:

```
style="position:absolute;"
```

in the "popUpHTML" variable. When you click on "Student name" the popup is rendered centrally, which (I think) is what you want?

Without doing this I found that bPopup behaved weirdly (a potential bug with bPopup?), though I was not entirely sure if what I was seeing was the issue you are having. If you remove the style I added to the popUpHTML string and press the link, the popup gets drawn to the left side of the screen. However *if you then adjust the viewport* in jsfiddle (i.e. the bottom right pane) the position of the popUp is changed, as this seems to trigger bPopup's position calculation.

Hence it could be that to solve your problem you need to explicitly set a position style in the student_iframe_container div which you render via "popUpHTML".

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts, Fresh. If it wasn't for you I wouldn't have gotten to the bottom of this at all I suspect - but unfortunately BQB's answer was the one that worked for me. +1 though and I hope others will too. For what it's worth, I think you were on the right lines!

Comment: @dunc No problems, glad you've fixed your issue. I'm sure I tried setting the width in the container, but it didn't work for me. This investigation was good for me as it was one of the first time I've really used jsFiddle for a seemingly complicated issue.

Comment: Yeah I wish I could use jsFiddle effectively for questions like this but when I've done it in the past I've been downvoted because the stuff I can set up in jsFiddle is too dissimilar to my working environment.